# How do I pass only current user data to be filtered in django-filter?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using `django-filter` to filter my data. The issue is both the available options of the filters and the results are based on all the data, not only on the curent user.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_added = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I used the code below to filter the results only on the current user:

**filters.py**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super(ProductFilter, self).qs
        user = getattr(self.request, "user", None)
        return parent.filter(user=user).order_by("-timestamp")
```

In my `views.py` I tried to pass the queryset, but nothing changed:

```
class ProductsFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Product
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I am not sure how to limit the available filter options only on the current user's data.

So, summarizing how can I pass into the filterset just the current user's data and not pass the whole data into the filterset and then filter them on current user's data.

Comment: Can you share your "Product" model?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the Product model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**filters.py**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
        # And you can also do "lookup_expr='year__gt' and also 'year__lt'" 
        date_added = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='date_added', lookup_expr='year')
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = [] #You can add fields that wants to be displayed
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from .filters import ProductFilter

# Function Base View
@login_required
def productfilter(request):
     user = request.user
     product_list = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
     product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=product_list)
     return render(request, "template_name.html", {'products': product_list})

#Class Based View
class ProductsFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'template_name.html'
    filter_set = ProductFilter
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Why have you created a function instead of @GiannisIordanou's Class Based view?

Comment: I tried the get_queryset before posting the question, and the filter options are based on all data, not just current user's.