# Display data in a table only of the user logged in

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hello I want to display data of the user that is logged in form models into a table written in html

My views.py **{ I am displaying data from two different models in one table }**

```
 def managestugriev(request):
   from_stugrievance = studentgriev.objects.all()
   from_facgriev = facgrieve.objects.all()
   return render(request,'manageGriev.html', 
        {"data_form_stu":from_stugrievance,"data_from_fac":from_facgriev})
```

template.html

```
 <div>
    <div>
        <h2><center>Manage Your Grievances Here </h2>
        <h3>Your Total Grievances: {{data|length}}</h3>
        <h3></h3>
        <table class="center">  
            <thead>
                <tr text-align="justify">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Grievance</th>
                    <th>Date & Time</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Solution</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for i in data_form_stu %}
                    <tr text-align="justify">
                        <td padding:10px>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.grievance}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.date_time}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                        {% for i in data_from_fac%}
                        <td>{{i.solution}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                         </div>
                        </div>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

models.py **{Two models from which I am displaying the data}**

```
 class studentgriev(models.Model):
    ch = (
         ("Solved","Solved"),("Pending","Pending"),("Not Solved","Not Solved")
     )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='',null=False)
    contactnum = models.IntegerField(default='',null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,default='',null=False)
    grievance = models.TextField(default='',null=False)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=ch,default='')




def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " "

class facgrieve(models.Model):
    solution = models.TextField(default='',null=False) 


def __str__(self):
    return self.solution + " "
```

***Please can anyone help !***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having trouble with user.is\_authenticated in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032174/having-trouble-with-user-is-authenticated-in-django-template)

Comment: I think that the issue is your not filtering the user from the view. Try something like `from_stugrievance = studentgriev.objects.filter(author=userID)`

Comment: @Wazy Is author a keyword or a variable like should I write there ' name ' as per my models.py ?

Comment: author was just a place holder I used.

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799668/how-do-i-pass-only-current-user-data-to-be-filtered-in-django-filter/48800338